# how to create separate bar chart with JSON array set?

Tags: arrays, d3.js

I use this eample [link](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304) to customize.There are json array and create bar charts according to array.

Please guide me, this is my json format:

```
{ "server1": [
    {
      "mount": "test1",
      "value": 207
    },
    {
      "mount": "test2",
      "value": 20.07
    }
  ],

  "server2": [
    {
      "mount": "test1",
      "value": 45
    },
    {
      "mount": "test2",
      "value": 0.04
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to create 2 separate bar chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass value like data array and loop it!

`d3.json("./data/new.json", function(error,data1){`

`for(r in data1){`

like this you can implement this

Answer (score 2):

you can use loop for this

`$.getJSON("./data/new.json", function(data){`

`for(i in data){`

`alert(i);`

`data1 = data[i];`
after looping using your example this way [link](http://jsfiddle.net/lakshitha/3f0x5qma/)

Answer (score 0):

Convert this json to two list using javascript or jquery whichever you like

t1 = [207, 45]

t2 = [20.07, 0.04]

now replace data (d) in the http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304 with t1 for graph 1 and with t2 for graph 2
it will work for sure

Comment: can you give more detail for this?? i mean cord example.